# Variación de resultado de consulta del total de precio de compra por cantidad en la tabla productos en SQL Server

Tags: sql

necesito saber el total del precio de compra por el stock, tengo el inventario en Excel donde me da un resultado de **254.819,37**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este resultado **254.786,58** me sale al hacer la consulta en SQL Server.

```
Select SUM(PrecioCompra*Stock) FROM Productos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los precios y las cantidades están iguales ya los revisé.

**¿A QUE SE DEBE ESTO Y COMO PODRIA RESOLVERLO?**

Comment: Ley del redondeo... yo veo hasta 4 decimales en excel, y 2 en SQl.

Comment: Igual en Excel con dos decimales sale lo mismo

Comment: Entonces hay algo mal, en tu BD o en el EXCEL. Podrías crear una copia para revisar ambos ?